# How do I parse the byte data packet from uart into communication packets in C#?

Tags: c#, uart

'

```
    private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Veri okuduğun alan
        string data = "";
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                data += Program.serial.ReadByte().ToString("X") + " ";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(data);

        Program.serial.DiscardInBuffer();
    }
```

'
When I connect to the port, I can exchange data. How do I make the data I read meaningful, byte by byte? I want to check the correctness of the start and end packets of my 12-byte packet that starts with 0xFF and ends with 0xFE, so I need to split the data that comes to me into bits and check, I don't know how

Comment: Well that depends on what the meaning is, doesn't it? What is the sender supposed to be sending?

Comment: I want to check the correctness of the start and end packets of my 12-byte packet that starts with 0xFF and ends with 0xFE, so I need to split the data that comes to me into bits and check, I don't know how

Comment: Please edit your question and include this information in your question. It should not be required to read the comments to get an understanding of your problem - the question itself should contain all the pertinent information to understand what the problem is and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So you just want to find where the 0xFF and 0xFE is. When you see a 0xFF then that's the start of the packet. When you see a 0xFE that's the end of the packet. If you don't see a 0xFE then the packet hasn't ended yet so keep receiving data to add on to the same packet.

Comment: Change  From string data = ""; To List<byte> data = new List<byte>();   Then From data += Program.serial.ReadByte().ToString("X") + " "; To data.Add(Program.serial.ReadByte())  Finally convert to a string : string results = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

Comment: – user253751- I'm getting the correct data you said, but I don't know how to check the correctness of the starter package, how to separate these packages

Comment: @HandeGoroglu Make a variable that says whether it's currently in a packet. Read one byte at a time. If the byte is 0xFF, clear the string and set the in-packet variable to true. If the byte is 0xFE and the in-packet variable is true, set it to false and print out the string. Otherwise if the in-packet variable is true then add the byte to the string. Do you see how that could work?

Comment: @user253751 yesss! :)